# Methods with the same name as their class will not be constructors in a future version of PHP; mPDF has a deprecated constructor

Tags: php, codeigniter, mpdf

I use Mpdf to generate pdf in codeigniter and other projects are all ok generating pdf with these mpdf instructions.
But in one project, I'm having a problem(error on the following screenshoot) after I click print button. Maybe the problem in the file size? (print data has about 25000 lines). How can I solve?

I hope someone can help me.Please!

Answer (score 0):

Your mPDF version is not compatible with your PHP version. Update mPDF at least to version 7.0.